# Where to find OLE Automation's documentation

Tags: vbscript, ms-word, ole

Indeed this is a very basic question but I unable to find any official documentation of the Microsoft OLE Automation interface.

I would like to interract with Word and Excel through VBScript or Perl. I found plenty of examples on google but it would be much easier to get the full API documentation and it seems I cannot find anything on google even with these keywords: Microsoft, API, OLE, documentation, man, list of methods, library...

I am starting from this point:

```
 my $excel= Win32::OLE->new('Excel.Application')
```

Now where can I find all the available methods for this object ? Is there any official documentation somewhere ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Word/Excel etc Press **Alt + F11** then **F2**. It's self documenting. Search on *Word Object Model* and *VBA* and *Office Developer* (there a whole web site section on MSDN). Hint try [www.msdn.com/office](http://www.msdn.com/office)

To your question, which is irrelevent to your problem. It is the the

```
The Component Object Model Specification

Draft Version 0.9, October 24, 1995

Microsoft Corporation and Digital Equipment Corporation

Copyright © 1992-95 Microsoft Corporation.
```

That is the base standard. As modified since then it is in the COM topic in the Windows Platform SDK.

Answer (score 1):

You won't get far, if you instantiate an object named ($)word with Excel(.Application).

To get all necessary information use the Help and Object Catalog of the Word, Excel, ... applications.

Comment: ^^ My mistake, I'm working with both word and excel :)